# How to load Module from another Angular Project?

Tags: angular, microservices, lazy-loading, spring-cloud, angular-lazyloading

I just play around with Angular and Spring Clound Microservices.

I have a Main Angular Project with a Menu, I do a request to my Gateway and receive a List of all available Microservices currently online. Based on this List my Menu is dynamicly built.

Example:

Menu : Microservice 1 | Microservice 2

On click on "Microservice 1" I want to load the content of a module that is inside of another angular project delivered with Microservice 1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single-spa framework with angualr.single-spa is a javascript framework for front-end microservices and can be implemented with angular . you need to use Micro-Frontend Architecture .

- https://morioh.com/p/b62bf13246cc
- https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-implement-micro-frontend-architecture-with-angular-e6828a0a049c
- https://medium.com/@rohitsaxena_97625/angular-angular-micro-frontend-part-of-adventures-in-micro-frontend-series-part-2-9e3c3f0bfc0c